# REST API - execute multiple actions

Tags: acumatica

Currently trying to work out how to use REST API to execute an action.
I added the ReverseInvoice action from Bills screen on my endpoints. And seems execute fine. Unfortunately, executing an action does not return a result e.g. 204 No Content. I'd wish to extract the RefNbr of the Debit Adj. raised.

[image]

Second problem is how do you stack actions or call series of actions ? The raised Debit Adj is not Released. So it seems ReverseInvoice & Release need to be executed at the same time. Plus, I also need them to be allocated against each other automatically.

I've got a feeling the REST API is not the way to go with this one.

Cheers and thanks for responses.

Comment: It seems like this should all be in the documentation for 'acumatica,' or I'd consider it a horrible product. I read their wiki entry, and it already smells funny to me. Good luck, consult the docs. Calling a series of actions will probably require some actual programming.
http://asiablog.acumatica.com/2016/09/acumatica-rest-api.html

Comment: Executing an action is documented. But not a series of it. There doesn't seem to any examples around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you're correct on both points: Acumatica's Contract-based API (both SOAP and REST flavors) doesn't allow you to get the entity that is a result of an action (you can only get the status of action invocation), and if you want to chain a sequence of action you'll have to do that manually from the client (call one action, check for the status, call the second one, check, raise, rinse, repeat). Or you can write a customization with a custom action that call two actions in sequence, and call that from the API.